# R adicionar uma coluna

Tags: r, tidyverse

Exemplo básico de uma página tutorial

[Exemplo](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/graphics-for-communication.html)

Temos

```
library(tidyverse)

##mpg

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = class)) +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE) +
  labs(title = "Fuel efficiency generally decreases with engine size")
```

Gera o gráfico

Nesta base temos duas colunas: `cty` e `hwy`
que representam o consumo na cidade e na estrada,
respectivamente.

```
manufacturer model      displ  year   cyl trans      drv     cty   hwy fl    class
   <chr>        <chr>      <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>      <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>
 1 audi         a4           1.8  1999     4 auto(l5)   f        18    29 p     comp~
 2 audi         a4           1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) f        21    29 p     comp~
```

Tentei criar uma coluna da média , `(cty+hwy)/2` e chamei de `avgc` para fugir de palavra reservada.

```
mpg %>% mutate(avgc = round((cty+hwy)/2))

   manufacturer model     displ  year   cyl trans drv     cty   hwy fl    class  avgc
   <chr>        <chr>     <dbl> <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
 1 audi         a4          1.8  1999     4 auto~ f        18    29 p     comp~    24
 2 audi         a4          1.8  1999     4 manu~ f        21    29 p     comp~    25
```

gera , mas não "persiste" pois se tento

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, avgc)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = class)) +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE) +
  labs(title = "Fuel efficiency generally decreases with engine size")
```

ocorre o seguinte erro

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : objeto 'avgc' não encontrado
```

Pergunto :

1. O campo ficou como *dbl* , é isto ? Como se converte para *int* ?
2. Que erro cometi ? Pois pelo Help e Doc que achei parece estar certo

Obs , Analista de Sistema se aventurando no R Studio.

Answer (score 6):

É porque você gerou a variável "avgc" mas não atribuiu ao objeto.
Observe que você digitou `mpg %>% mutate(avgc = round((cty+hwy)/2))`
Para ter salvo a nova coluna no dataset, precisaria usar o operador de atribuição `OBJETO <- mpg %>% mutate(avgc = round((cty+hwy)/2))`.

No exemplo abaixo, salvo a nova coluna no objeto "mpg2", para não alterar o objeto "mpg" original:

```
mpg2 <-  mpg %>% mutate(avgc = round((cty+hwy)/2))
```

Em seguida, replico o seu código, alterando apenas o dataset para "mpg2":

```
ggplot(mpg2, aes(displ, avgc)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = class)) +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE) +
  labs(title = "Fuel efficiency generally decreases with engine size")
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Erro bobo , valeu.